# While loop to populate datagridview with array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have a set of data that I need to populate a data grid view with once it reaches a certain point in the text file.

Once the `(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileOpen))` reaches [HRData] in the file I would like to store each column into an array for storing into a datagridview and looping to the end of the file

```
[HRData]
91  154 70  309 83  6451
91  154 70  309 83  6451
92  160 75  309 87  5687
94  173 80  309 87  5687
96  187 87  309 95  4662
100 190 93  309 123 4407
101 192 97  309 141 4915
103 191 98  309 145 5429
106 190 99  309 157 4662
106 187 98  309 166 4399
107 186 97  309 171 4143
107 185 97  309 170 4914
108 184 96  309 171 5426
108 183 95  309 170 5688
```

Comment: @dotctor i have tried storing the values in string [] dataarray as a global variable using dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataArray[0],dataArray[1], etc );

Comment: @dotctor Hey, It is storing all the values in the 1st cell in the 1st column how do i split it to the other columns? Im relatively new to c# as a language Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use LINQ to produce a list (each element is a line) of arrays (each element is number in that line)

```
List<string[]> result = File.ReadAllLines("filePath") //read all lines in the file
    .SkipWhile(x => x != "[HRData]") //skip lines until reaching the "[HRData]"
    .Select(x => x.Split(null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) //split line by whitespace to get numbers in line
    .ToList(); // convert the result to a list
```

you can then use `result.ForEach(x => dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x))`